# Is it accurate to take the maximum distance between CDF and ECDF only at the edges? (Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test)

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have two samples, one obtained empirically and the other is the result of a simulation. I want to tune the simulation so that the result resembles the reality, for that I will minimize the KS statistic between the two samples.

I notice that when computing the KS statistic manually or when using a library (SciPy) the results are different, and that is due to the fact that the library only looks for the maximum in the edges rather than in the whole step of the distribution (see Figures).

**My question**: Is actually correct to only measure the distance in the edges of the ECDF or should one also measure along all the steps (interpolated)?

**Additional Note**: I am not interested in the p-value because this will be used for optimization, my question is whether I should you the KS statistic with or without interpolation or whether there are more appropriate approaches.

To illustrate here the Figures and Python code:

Manual Approach:

```
# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11692365/7690767
def cal_ecdf(sample): 
    return np.sort(sample), np.linspace(0, 1, len(sample), endpoint=False)

np.random.seed(42)

sample_expected = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=100) # This will be replaced with the empirical data
sample_actual = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=30) # This 

xs_expected, ys_expected = cal_ecdf(sample_expected)
plt.step(xs_expected, ys_expected, alpha=0.6, linestyle="--", label="Expected")

xs_actual, ys_actual = cal_ecdf(sample_actual)
plt.step(xs_actual, ys_actual, alpha=0.6, linewidth=2, label="Actual", where="post")
```

Without Interpolation:

[image]

Without interpolation, the max error found is **0.113**

Custom Interpolation:

```
xs_expected, ys_expected = cal_ecdf(sample_expected)
xs_actual, ys_actual = cal_ecdf(sample_actual)

xs_interpolated = np.union1d(xs_expected, xs_actual)

interpolation_expected = interp1d(xs_expected, ys_expected, kind="previous", fill_value='extrapolate')
ys_expected = interpolation_expected(xs_interpolated)
plt.step(xs_interpolated, ys_expected, alpha=0.6, linestyle="--", label="Expected", where="post")

interpolation_actual = interp1d(xs_actual, ys_actual, kind="previous", fill_value='extrapolate')
ys_actual = interpolation_actual(xs_interpolated)
plt.step(xs_interpolated, ys_actual, alpha=0.6, linewidth=2, label="Actual", where="post")
```

[image]

When using interpolation, the max error found is **0.137**

SciPy Results:

```
max_error, p_value = stats.ks_2samp(sample_expected, sample_actual)
print(f"Max Error {max_error:2.3f}") # 0.113
```

SciPy result agrees with the approach without interpolation.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by the "edges" in this context.

Comment: In the graph the ECDF is represented as a step function, what I notice is that scipy only looks for the maximum either at the beginning or the end of each step, not throughout the step iteself. Here these "beginning and end" would be the edges. It also match the definnition of the bin edges used for the calculation of the CDF, in this case the np.linspace output inside cal_ecdf

Comment: Because the reference distribution is non-decreasing, the extreme distances it attains relative to any horizontal segment must occur at that segment's endpoints.